# Can't convert json data into string after json_decode in php

Tags: php, json, unicode, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get JSON response with unicode characters from wikipedia API with php.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('http://my.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=နေဝင်း၊_ကောလိပ်ဂျင်&format=json&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content');
    $obj=json_decode($url,true);
    var_dump ($obj);
?>
```

If I use "true" parameter it returns as array. And I can't use it as string.
If I don't use "true" parameter it returns as objstd. I can't also use it as string. I got errors. I need to decode it since it contains unicode characters. If I decode it. I can't use it as string. Any ideas?

Comment: edited.Sry. I pressed tab and enter,It posts automatically,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned code is already a string - so there's no need to decode it.

You may still want to decode it first to check the validity though.

```
$url = json_decode($url, true); 
$url = json_encode($url, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
var_dump($url);
```

Comment: Dumping $url. Gets json response like this.string '{"query":{"normalized":[{"from":"\u1014\u1031\u101d\u1004\u103a\u1038\u104a_\u1000\u1031\u102c\u101c\u102d\u1015\u103a\u1002\u103b\u1004\u103a","to":........... etc.I need to decode to see the characters

Comment: JSON can only be represented as a valid UTF-8 string. Depending on your PHP version, you might be able to do this:

    `$url = json_decode($url, true);
    $url = json_encode($url, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    var_dump($url);`

Comment: My php version is 5.4.16.Let me make this clear.When I use decode_json,I can see the characters which is unicode.But I can't find a way to use it as string.When I don't use decode_json,I can't see the unicode characters,I get characters like this \u1‌​000\u1031\u102c\u101c\u102d\.